# Removing '\' in JQ Transform

Tags: jqtransform

I'm trying to use JQ Transform (https://jqplay.org/) on a JSON object, which I would like to store as string, but it always replaces " with \"

How can I get rid of this \ ?

Input JSON:
{"intents":[],"entities":[]}

JQ filter:
.|tostring

Output JSON:
{\"intents\":[],\"entities\":[]}

I know I would get desired result using Raw Output, but I cannot use it. I can only modify .|tostring filter.
Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use gsub to filter the string.

Input json:

```
{"intents":[],"entities":[]}
```

jq filter:

```
jq '.|tostring|gsub("\\\"";"")'
```

Output json:

```
"{intents:[],entities:[]}"
```